# Footnote and citation at the end of a sentence

Tags: citation, reference, footnotes

According to [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9632/footnote-marks-at-end-of-a-sentence), footnote marks should come at the end of the sentence, after the punctuation, like

> The inner flow is then reflected at this boundary, leading to an oblique expansion shock (also named reflection wave).<sup>4</sup>

Sadly, I don't remember where, but I think that references go like this:

> The inner flow is then reflected at this boundary, leading to an oblique expansion shock (also named reflection wave)[8].

Now, assuming I have to put both of these,

> The inner flow is then reflected at this boundary, leading to an oblique expansion shock (also named reflection wave)[8].<sup>4</sup>

is this the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Citation references do normally go inside the sentence, i.e. before the full stop (that's the only thing I don't like about numeric superscript references - the gap underneath and before the full stop is ugly). A footnote to the whole sentence can certainly be placed after the full stop. If you don't like the combination, it's often possible to apply the citation or footnote to a  specific statement within the sentence, rather than putting it at the end.

Comment: That does seem like it will solve the issue. As a follow-up, is there any rule about spacing before or after the superscript? In my texts, I've been using a smaller space after the mark, because a normal one seems to large for me...

Comment: I've never seen any reason to use anything other than a normal space, but I don't know if LaTeX  does anything clever behind the scenes.  I reckon I'd have heard something if it did